# Buttons center as co-ordination origin

Tags: objective-c

At the moment I have a button on a ScrollView that zooms. I've made the button stay in the same place relative to the position on the image when you zoom, but since the button's origin is (0,0), it ends up moving about a centimetre. Is there anyway I can set the buttons origin to be in the very middle of the button?

How I'm displaying my buttons:

```
UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(_openMiamiPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btn1.tag = kAddContactButton;
[_mapContentView addSubview:btn1];
```

-Getting co-ordinatons from a plist.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific in that: "set the buttons origin to be in the very middle of the button". I just don't understand what you are up to.

Comment: @Hermann Klecker If I have a square button and set its location to 0,0 on the screen. it will fit exactly into the top left hand corner of the screen because the origin of its axis/co-ordination is at its very top-left point. I want the origin to be in the middle so that if I was to have the square at 0,0, i would only see 1/4th of the square as its top half and left half are not in the view. This is the best example I can give.

Answer (score 1):

```
btn1.center = GCPointMake(0,0);
```

Comment: Guess you meant `CGPointZero`.

Comment: Neither of these work, it looks exactly the same as it did before. If you read my comment to Caleb, you will get a better understanding of what i'm after.

Comment: No, I did not mean GPointZero although I would use it in this very case. I meant to point out the way of positioning a view by its center coordinate. And CGPiontZero is much more general.

Comment: @SinaYamani, each view is positioned within its superview's coorinate systen. Which means 0,0 is usually the top left point of the area covered by the superview. With a scroll view that may be different. 0,0 of the content area does not need to be the top left part of the scroller nor does it need to be in the top left of the screen. Did you check your UIScrollView coordinates, bounds, zoomlevel and properties etc?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway I can set the buttons origin to be in the very middle of the button?

It helps to be specific about what coordinate system you're talking about. Any view, your button included, works with (at least) two coordinate systems: its own, and its superview's. The view's own coordinate system is the one in which the view draws itself. The superview's coordinate system is the one in which the view is positioned inside the superview.

It sounds like you just want to move your button so that the center is at the superview's origin. If that's the case, Hermann Klecker's answer is correct -- just set the button's `center` property to a point that represents the origin. Properties like `center` and `frame` are expressed in the superview's coordinate system.

**Update:** The `center` property represents [the center of the frame](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/center). Changing it *will* very definitely move the button. If you assigned (0,0) to `center` and the button didn't move to where you want it, then the coordinate system of the button's superview isn't what you're expecting. You say that your button is in a scroll view, but you need to realize that the button's superview is the scroll view's content view, not the scroll view itself. Setting the button's `center` to (0,0) moves the button to the top left corner of the content view, the area that moves inside the scroll view. If you want the button to remain stationary while content scrolls underneath it, put the button *on top* of the scroll view, not inside it.

Comment: Herman's method didn't work. I made an image to describe what I'm looking for. The background of the image is the superview which is the ScrollView, and the button is at point 0,0 of the ViewController. The top part of the image is what it looks like at point 0,0, this is because the origin of the button is the top left point of its .png image, which is where the picture starts. What I'm after is having the origin being in the middle of the picture, so if I had a 50x50 image, its middle point would be 25x25, which would look like the bottom image.

Comment: that isn't a much of a choice for me, since the button needs to be relative to the scrollview's position when zooming. If I put it on top, when I zoom, the button will stay in the same place whilst the background would zoom.